# JMeter read the second sheet of CSV

Tags: csv, jmeter

How can I make JMeter read the **second** sheet of my CSV?

I want to use CSV Data Set Config.

Normally, it reads the first line of the first sheet but is there any way to be a bit more flexible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can use CSV Data Set Config for that, you should add external code for example using [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi),

Download the jar file and place it in JMETER_HOME lib folder, and then write the code in JSR223 Element.

[Examples](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Example:_Parsing_an_Excel_CSV_File) exists, code for get second record:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in);
// go to next record
records.next();
CSVRecord secondRecord = records.next();
//columnOne = secondRecord.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSV file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) doesn't have "sheets", it is a normal plain text file using delimiters in order to represent structured data.

If you are trying to get data from i.e. [Microsoft Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) file type - unfortunately you won't be able to do it using CSV Data Set Config. The easiest would be exporting data as separate plain-text CSV files.

If you don't have the possibility to do the export you still can access the data from Excel files but it will be a little bit more tricky as you will have to use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language and [Apache POI libraries](https://poi.apache.org/)

More information:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)